# Is this set weakly compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $\mathcal C^0(M) =\{f:M\to \mathbb R; f\ \text{is continuous}\}$. Suppose that $T:\mathcal C^0(M) \to \mathcal C^0(M)$ a bounded linear operator such that $T$ is a positive operator, i.e. for every $0\leq f\in \mathcal C^0(M)$ we have $0\leq Tf$.

Assume that there exists $h \in \mathcal C^0(M),$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \|T^n(\mathbf 1) - h\|_{\infty} = 0, \quad \quad (*)$$
where $\mathbf 1 : x \in M \to 1\in \mathbb R.$

> **Question:** I would like to know if hypothesis $(*)$ implies that for every $f\in\mathcal C^0(M),$ the set
> $$\{T^n f\}_{n\in \mathbb N}, \quad (**)$$
> is relative weakly compact.

Does the hypothesis $(*)$ helps to get that $(**)$ is relative weakly compact?

Comment: Is $h$ supposed to be $g$, here?

Comment: Yes, I changed, thx.

Comment: Do you really want compactness or relativ compactness/precompactness? Because your set will probably usually not be weakly closed.

Comment: I want relative weakly compactness, sorry.